# Oracle Query to get data

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

Please help to how to write the Oracle query to get the result 
 **(in 3 seperate columns)** like  "**abcd  1,5,7 xyz**" from below table,**I want to include COL3 as a seprate column**. Please help

```
 Oracle Database table
    ======================
    col1  |  col2 | col3
    ======================
    ABCD      1     xyz
    ======================
    EDF       3     lmn
    ======================
    ABCD      5     xyz
    ======================
    ABCD      7     xyz
    ======================

    Thanks in advance. :)
```

Comment: google for group concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   col1, listagg(col2, ',') within group (order by col2) as new_col_name
from     table_name
group by col1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works coool :)

Comment: Hi,  -  If a solution works for you in your situation, it is customary to mark the question as Answered so that volunteers on SO can focus on questions that haven't been answered yet. Cheers!

Comment: Done :) I was trying to mark as an answer, but stackoverflow was not allowing me...., hahah, again thanks for your answer

Comment: Hi Math guy, I need one more help from you,Please check I have edited my querstion.

Comment: Please show by way of your example what the output should look like.

Comment: Thanks for reponse @mathGuy, I want to avoid the one column ,                   SELECT
LISTAGG(CSP_GROUP, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CSP_GROUP) AS NEW_COL_NAME,
UCP_GROUP, RANK,BILLING_ROLE,BBNMS_ROLE,CREATED_USER_ID,UPDATED_USER_ID,UPDATED_TIME_STAMP,SASVP_ROLE
FROM   UCP_GROUP_MAPPING
GROUP BY UCP_GROUP,RANK,BILLING_ROLE,BBNMS_ROLE,CREATED_USER_ID,UPDATED_USER_ID,UPDATED_TIME_STAMP,SASVP_ROLE